# Implement Api to storing credential of facebook/twitter or something else

Tags: python, ios, django

I'm writing an internal API for mobile device like iPhone or Android.

I want with these device, that the users can connect with the app only via Facebook Connect or Twitter Connect.

I don't know iOS but I want to prepare the code in the backend.

How must I prepare the code? I'm using Python/Django and Tastypie for the API.
I have experience with [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) that support very well these two social networks.

How can I create the api for accepting new user registered from twitter o facebook and storing their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is, After the user authenticates using any of the social networks on the device, Get the name,email,deviceid  and  any other relevant details, and store those details on the server like a normal registration.[i.e maintain your own user id rather than fb_id or twitter_id]

If there is a requirement to use your we service from a browser, when you are inserting user records generate a random password and mail it the user, and store the hash in the database.

Comment: Greit! So simple, thanks. If someone have another hints or suggest please post here.